# How to make edittext lose focus when 'Return' key is pressed?

Tags: android, android-edittext, return, lost-focus

When I press 'Return' key in `EditText`, it is making new line by making it bigger.
How to make `EditText` lose focus when 'Return' key is pressed? In other words, how to make keyboard disappear when 'Return' is pressed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use following short of code to get event of Return and disappear keyboard.

```
(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1)).setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {
    public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (keyCode == 66) {
            hideKeyboard(v);
            return true; //this is required to stop sending key event to parent
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

In above code `66` is code for `Return` You can also use `KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER` as preferred by @JJPA.

Following is code to hide keyboard explicitly.

```
private void hideKeyboard(View view) {
    InputMethodManager manager = (InputMethodManager) view.getContext()
            .getSystemService(INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    if (manager != null)
        manager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
}
```

Comment: This is hiding keyboard but could not prevent making new line. How to deal with that?

Comment: @JoeRichard, I have edited my answer with `return true;` (upper half code in answer). This will prevent new line. :)

Comment: @JoeRichard, I don't have any problem with my code. I am remove characters by using "BackSpace". May be you did some changes in code or other which reflects that? Please check again.

Answer (score 3):

Avoid displaying the return key if you don't want user to press it.

What you can do is, make the EditText singleLine and play around a little with android:nextFocus* to implement a more user friendly IME navigation. For your problem, you can simply modify your EditText from xml like

```
<EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/edit"
        android:singleLine="true"
/>
```

Comment: This method did not help. Return key anyway making new line.

Comment: Can you share the EditText xml layout? I have tested this piece of code

Answer (score 0):

You need to use TextWatcher so you can catch the \n character and modify text so there is no new lines, heres the magic:

```
mFirstEditText.addTextChangedListener( new TextWatcher() {

    private boolean mEnterOccurred;

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence text, int start, int before, int count) {
        String textStr = text.toString();
        if(textStr.contains("\n")) {
            // Wipe off the \n
            textStr = textStr.replace("\n", "");
            mEnterOccurred = true;
            mFirstEditText.setText(textStr);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence text, int start, int count, int after) {
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        if(mEnterOccurred) {
            // Change focus to another EditText
            mSecondEditText.requestFocus();
            // Change flag to default
            mEnterOccurred = false;
        }
    }
});
```